# Assuming a solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am working on exercise involving the PDE

> $\frac{1}{2}{\sigma}^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S^2}-rP+r\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}=0$

The solution I am looking at says to assume $S^{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is a real number and then works from there. Can anyone explain the idea behind this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an educated guess based on experience. For non-linear/non-homogeneous/non-autonomous ODEs there is no unifying approach to solve such an equation in general.

Your ODE is a so called [Euler equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx), for which it is known that the substitution $P=S^\lambda$ "works".

Normally for such a guess, the German word "Ansatz" is used, which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) defines as: "an ansatz is an educated guess that is verified later by its results".